# Determining area size of grid (reference grid) in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, grids-graticules, spatial-index, arcgis-10.7

How do I determine the area size (square kilometres) of a customised reference grid in ArcMap 10.7?

I have tried Data Driven Pages and it is not working for me. The idea is to know the area size of each grid  I made.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Have you tried measuring your "customised reference grid"?  Did you create that "customised reference grid"?  Is it a vector grid created using the Create Fishnet tool or something else?

Answer (score 2):

[image]Right click to dataframe and switch to Grids section. Create new grid and chose the option of **Measured Grid**. On the second step you have the option to chose the intervals. For your case if you want 1Km square you should chose 1000x1000m. You will have several other options to personalize the coordinate grid.

[image]

Comment: Bro this is how to create coordinate grid each 1000m, however your question is not so clear. Is this what you want, or you wanna create a datadriven pages for your area with rectangular with 1km square? Because Datadriven pages and coordinates grid have nothing to do with each other.